# Problems with Alfresco CMIS queries with dates and Alfresco 4.0.d

Tags: alfresco, cmis

I don't receive any results doing the following CMIS query:

```
SELECT * FROM cmis:document WHERE cmis:creationDate > TIMESTAMP '2001-01-01T00:00:00.000Z'
```

I'm using the node browser of Alfresco-Explorer, and I've tried *cmis-alfresco*, *cmis-string* and *solr-cmis*. But no success.

Edit:

Ok, here the response.

It seems to be a bug and is commented in [this thread](https://forums.alfresco.com/en/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=43067) and [bug ALF-12944](https://issues.alfresco.com/jira/browse/ALF-12944).

I'll try to use the old CMIS URL to see if it works.

Regards

Comment: don't have a 4.0b to test with, that query works fine on 3.4.0 and 3.4.7

Comment: I've found a workaround for my purpose (getting all elements for a specific date): `SELECT * from cmis:document WHERE CONTAINS('cmis:creationDate:\'2012-04-19\'')`.
This seems to have the nice effect to allow finding all documents for a natural month, year or hour, e.g: `SELECT * from cmis:document WHERE CONTAINS('cmis:creationDate:\'2012-04\'')` or `SELECT * from cmis:document WHERE CONTAINS('cmis:creationDate:\'2012-04-19T17:20\'')`

Comment: emy, since you've just been back to the site would you mind putting your "answer" in the above comment in a real "Answer", then activating the checkmark next to it to indicate it resolves your issue :-)?